# How to send data to Thingsboard via HTTP

Tags: json, csv, http, thingsboard

I am using **thingsboard** on my local machine (windows) and I need to send data from CSV file  with **HTTP POST** request, to do so I need to write a **JAVA** program which will allow sending data from a **JSON** file  to thingsboard platfom.
Do you have any suggestions how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a great guide on using thingsboards http api: [HTTP Device API Reference](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/). They use a handy commandline tool called *curl*. I'd go on as follows: 1st) read the guide and play around with curl and thingsboards api. 2nd) Check out, choose and setup a scripting environment (shell script, python, nodejs or something else). 3rd) Figure out how to read and process files and how to execute _curl_ with your scripting environment. 4) Write a script that reads your CSV, transforms to JSON and invokes curl to send it to thingsboard.

Comment: @lupz thank's a lot for your reply, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite straight forward, no need to authentications and it's about [Telemetry Upload API](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/). Since you do not have any example of your csv, and assuming for that you may find tons of guide I just bring here an example of performing a POST http request to THINGSBOARD server using python http client, based on your requirements it can be done in any language.

you should only:

- Convert your data from csv or any format to the following format in `data` dictionary, with proper timestamp as `ts` and other variables in a field of `values`. If you don't put `ts` it'll stamp the entry time of data on it. The `ts` must be in milliseconds.
- Convert it to json
- Use host IP address, the PORT and access token of that device in the url as in the example.

  ```
    import requests, json

    IP, PORT, access_token = ???.???.???.??? # host address of Thingsboard server
    PORT = 8080 # normally it should be 8080 
    access_token = XXXXXXXX # you can copy it easily from device panel of Thingsboard

    data = [
      {
        "ts": 1591123823000,
        "values": {
          "TEMPERATURES": 100,
          "DEW_POINT": 28,
          "VALUE_X": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "ts": 1591123883000,
        "values": {
          "TEMPERATURES": 150,
          "DEW_POINT": 26,
          "VALUE_X": 10
        }
      },
      {
        "ts": 1591123943000,
        "values": {
          "TEMPERATURES": 200,
          "DEW_POINT": 25,
          "VALUE_X": -10
        }
      }
    ]

    data = json.dumps(data) 

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}

    url_post = 'http(s)://{}:{}/api/v1/{}/telemetry'.format(IP, PORT, access_token)

    response = requests.post(url_post, headers=headers, data=data)
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've already converted my CSV file to Json, I'm using Java not Python, but in order to do so I don't want to write the data in my program, It should be passed in the request from the file that I've already created. is there any simple way to do that, I'm also trying to use the HTTP client API.